# Vue.js 3 - "export 'createStore' was not found in 'vuex'

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

i have this error when run my app  :

> WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                                                                                                                                                       11:50:40 PM
> warning  in ./src/store/store.js
> "export 'createStore' was not found in 'vuex'

I installed vuex by `npm install --save vuex`

I'm using vue 3

my Store.js:

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import Movie from './Modules/Movie';
import post from './Modules/post';

const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    post,
    Movie,
  },
});

export default store;
```

my main.js:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store/store.js';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(store);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You've installed the Vuex version 3.x by running `npm install --save vuex` you should uninstall it `npm uninstall --save vuex` then install the version 4 which is compatible with vue 3 by running the following command :

```
npm install --save vuex@next
```

For people using Yarn below is the command

```
yarn add vuex@next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ yarn remove vuex
$ yarn add vuex@next
```

This has fixed my issue!