# Overwritten typing errors with vuex

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm writing project with Vue 3 and TypeScript.

I have problem with vuex, I created a `vuex.d.ts` file for `$store` access inside Components:

```
import { Store } from 'vuex';
import { State } from '@/store';

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $store: Store<State>
    }
}
```

but when this file exists i have error inside file where I'm creating store.

```
TS2305: Module '"vuex"' has no exported member 'createStore'.
```

I'm using PhpStorm, maybe there is a problem. When I click on `vuex` import with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> this displays two type declarations. Original and my `vuex.d.ts` How to fix that error and have access to `$store` inside components?

Comment: Does the error occur in Phpstorm or on build too? Try to move `import`s inside `declare`, this seems to be a known issue.

Comment: Have you tried to disable ESLint by putting `/* eslint-disable */` at the first line?

Comment: Error occurs only in PhpStorm, build is correct. I cannot disable eslint because when vuex.d.ts file exists type for store not working when I imports store inside script files.

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150323/vue-js-3-export-createstore-was-not-found-in-vuex; if the tips from this post don't help, please share a project the issue can be repeated with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in `tsconfig.json`, I had to remove this lines:

```
"exclude": [
   "node_modules"
]
```